# Error: @angular/core/testing"' has no exported member 'beforeEach' after upgrading to angular rc.5

Tags: angular

I notice the following errors in `@angular/core/testing` after upgrading to angular rc.5:

```
@angular/core/testing"' has no exported member 'beforeEach'.
@angular/core/testing"' has no exported member 'beforeEachProviders'
@angular/core/testing"' has no exported member 'describe'
@angular/core/testing"' has no exported member 'xdescribe'
..
```

After upgrading to angular rc.5. I am unable to figure out why this is happening? [Changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) hasn't helped me so far. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of those alias were marked as deprecated since rc.4

And I guess, that they just forgot to add for a Changelog notice, that they have removed them completely.

This commit (part of rc.5) contains those changes
https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/9af2d8b

Just remove them and that's all (if your IDE will complain about them, just add them to custom typings)

Comment: How does one add them to custom typings?